# PHP - Return Array As String

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, implode

I have been searching for an answer to a PHP code problem. While it may sound easy to some users, I am having problem below:

I managed to retrieve data from a particular table with PHP and MySql. Unfortunately, I am unable to display result as a string rather than array.

I used `print_r($loggedin_users).`

**Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Test ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Test1 ) )
```

I have tried using implode function to return me a string.

**Result:**

```
ArrayArray
```

May I know how do I get a result as below?

**Desired result:**

```
Test; Test1
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To get values from first column use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php): `echo implode("; ", array_column($loggedin_users, 0));` See [test at eval.in](https://eval.in/418610)

Comment: Done, your answer helped me alot. Apologies for not accepting earlier. New to Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, that you have a two dimensional array. So you are trying to implode two arrays, which can't work. So you first have to implode the subArrays and then implode it again, e.g.

```
echo implode(";", array_map("implode", $loggedin_users));
```

**Side note:**

If you would have [`error reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) turned on you would have got a notice, saying:

> **Notice:** Array to string conversion

Comment: Ah, precisely why I am not getting it right at all. I will read more on two dimensional array. 

Your code has fixed the problem and I appreciate your time in looking into the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
echo array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item) {
    if(is_null($carry)) {
        return $item[0];
    } else {
        return $carry . "; " . $item[0];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach` them use `implode` because you have multidimensional array.

```
foreach($loggedin_users as $key => $val){
  $string = implode(', ', $val);
}
```

Comment: This will just keep overwriting `$string` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a recursive function here. so, no matter what array it is and no matter upto what extent that is nested. you'll always get desired result.

```
$a = array(
 0 => array(0 => 'Test'),
 1 => array(0 => 'Test1')
);

function implodeCustom($array){
    $string = "";
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    if(is_array($value)){
        $string .= implodeCustom($value);
    } else{
        $string .= $value.";";
    }
    return $string;
}

echo rtrim(implodeCustom($a),';');
```